# How to use 'or' option in typescript-sequelize with node.js?

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I use [typescript-sequelize](https://github.com/RobinBuschmann/sequelize-typescript)

how to use `findOne({where: {something or something2}});`
I read doc, I can't understand
help me

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First you have to import the `Op`:

```
import {Op} from "sequelize";
```

Then create your where clause like this:

```
findOne({where: {
  value_to_find: {
    [Op.or]: {
      [Op.eq]: something,
      [Op.eq]: something2
    }
  }
}})
```

Comment: This works with "sequelize": "^6.13.0" and "sequelize-typescript": "^2.1.2". For old version, this won't work.